# Create and copy Tables in Local database from Client DB

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

I'm working on some project. But for some test purposes I need some tables from client oracle DB to my local DB. So that I could perform operations on that tables for test purposes.

Can you please help me ?

Comment: Is your local DB also Oracle?

Comment: You probably need all the tables due to foreign key considerations.  I suggest doing a restore from backup to your local machine.  Better yet do a restore to a test server.

Comment: @Hambone, Yes Hambone, Its oracle

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to get a dump of your client DB with expdp. But you need to have access to conolse of the client computer.
If you have no Access you could try to set up an database link from you database to the client one (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm).

Exect you have now your db link "MyDBLink" and want to copy the dual table you can use the create table as select Statement to create a copy to your System:

```
create table myCopyOfDual as select * from dual@MyDBLink
```